# Fragment remove on navigating to it once again

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

So I have functionality where I need to eliminate a fragment from backstack if I navigate to same fragment once again.
(i.e)
On navigating

> A --> B --> C --> A

backstack should become

> B --> C --> A

I tried to remove with below code

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
```

But it removes only the screen. Backstack still remains unchanged. So onBackPress it requires more backpresses to close the screen or app.

I also tried to use `popbackstack(name:String)` and `popbackstackImmediate(name:String)` methods but both of them popped all the fragments above the identified one provided
POP_BACKSTACK_INCLUSIVE flag removes the identified one also.

So is there anyway to remove only the fragment that is desired to remove from backstack?
Also I need to know whether removing fragment from backstack like that could cause any problems in app performance.